# Bad padding exception in AES

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am working on a project where I need to send verification link to user. So encrypted his username using AES encrytion. My code works fine, i.e, encryption and decrytpion are working fine but only in the program when I tested it. I encrypted a string and then decrypted it. It works fine 'locally'.

The problem is, when I send email with activation link and click on it, it gives me error:

**`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`**

My code is as shown below:

```
public class AES {

private static final String algo="AES";
private static final byte[] keyValue= 
        new byte[]{somekey};

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception{

    Key key= new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, algo);

    return key;
}

public static String encrypt(String  email) throws Exception{

    Key key=generateKey();
    Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance(algo);
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encVal=c.doFinal(email.getBytes());
    String encryptedEmail= new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);

    return encryptedEmail;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedEmail) throws Exception{

    Key key=generateKey();
    Cipher c=Cipher.getInstance(algo);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] decodeEmail= new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedEmail);
    byte[] decodedEmail=c.doFinal(decodeEmail);

    String decryptedEmail= new String(decodedEmail);

    return decryptedEmail;
    }
```

}

Comment: Is there anyone who would help me? Please, it's urgent!

Comment: `BadPaddingException` is thrown *whenever* anything is wrong with the input of the algorithm (key or ciphertext in your case). Did you compare the output of the base 64 encoding/decoding? You should not use internal Sun classes, try Bouncy Castle or Apache libraries instead.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? If so, could you indicate what did and either accept or post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to run using the Base64 encoder/decoder of Bouncy Castle libraries, no problem at all. Check your input/output and use a valid base 64 encoder/decoder, not a Sun internal one with unspecified input/output.

Warning: as you use unspecified character encoding it will use the platform specific one, so your input/output may be different on separate systems. Try and use Charset.forName("UTF8") for the most compatible character encoding (in the String constructor and `toBytes` method).

Comment: I would bet on the character encoding as the issue.

Comment: @GregS maybe, it could be that the base64 string is not tranferred properly, otherwise the conversion could fail silently, but that would be *after* decryption

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not appear to be setting padding on either encryption or decryption.  It is far better to explicitly set the padding at both ends.  You also do not appear to be setting a mode, again that needs to be done explicitly.

I would suggest "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" as an obvious choice.

Comment: All very true, but as AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding is used by default, it does not constitute an answer.

Comment: ECB mode is insecure, avoid it.  CBC or CTR are secure.  Use GCM if you want authentication as well.  Better not to rely on defaults, it can lead to errors.  What is the default at the receiving end?

Comment: I think the receiving end is included in the code (both encrypt and decrypt are specified); the problem is that the code is actually working fine. Note: I'm not the author of the question.

Comment: Ya the code is working fine.. I mean, it is working fine when I execute main(). I pass a string, display after encrypting it and then display it again after decrypting it. Its all fine till this. But when I send an email containing a link with encrypted string as a parameter, I get exception on visiting the link.

Comment: Are you decrypting the e-mail on the same machine or on a different machine?  Have you checked that the received encrypted e-mail is byte-for-byte the same as the e-mail you sent?